# seeding user meal booking table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Seeding Database tables Seeding user data.... Seeding meals data .... Seeding user meal booking data .... rails aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method` UserMealBooking' for nil:NilClass

## assuming the user's email address is "user@example.com"

```
    meals = Meal.all
    user = User.find_by(email_address`your text`: "user@example.com")
    userbooking1 = user.UserMealBooking.create!(meal_id: meals.first.id, booking_type: "online", booking_date: "2023-05-12T10:00")
```

i want when a user books a meal their id can be shown or email
`your text``

Comment: Can you share your models please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a class from an object, this doesn't seem right `user.UserMealBooking`

I assume `UserMealBooking` it is the model between the user and the meal
so there multiple ways of creating the association, one of them is

```
    meals = Meal.all
    user = User.find_by(email_address`your text`: "user@example.com")
    userbooking1 = UserMealBooking.create!(meal_id: meals.first.id, user_id: user.id, booking_type: "online", booking_date: "2023-05-12T10:00")
```

Make sure there are meals and a user with a specific email in your database

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `User` model has a `has_many` association with the `UserMealBooking` model. In that case, you can modify your code like below:

```
meals = Meal.all
user = User.find_by(email_address`your text`: "user@example.com")
userbooking1 = user.user_meal_bookings.create!(meal_id: meals.first.id, booking_type: "online", booking_date: "2023-05-12T10:00")
```